# Search multiple column array for data and return data from another column in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to search the array G2:I248 for the term in cell J1. If any of the cells in the array match the name in cell J1, then I need it to return the data in the corresponding row in range B2:B248 to cell A1.
There will be multiple cells with matching data in them.

In this example, I need to search all of the rows in all three event columns {array G2:I248} for the event Softball(Girls) {cell J1}. In cells A1 and A2 it should return the names Aria and Audrey Ella.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5ixd.png)

I have tried =filter and =vlookup......this is just too complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=tocol(index(if(G2:I248=J1,B2:B248,)),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using the  filter function in google sheets
Search the array  G2:I248 for the term in cell J1 and return the corresponding names from the B2:B248 range

```
=FILTER(B2:B248, (G2:G248=J1) + (H2:H248=J1) + (I2:I248=J1))
```

Place this formula in cell A1, and it will return the names that match the event in cell J1. If there are multiple matches and they will appear in consecutive cells below A1